# How CPU/OS maintains info of all the processes and all the data in secondary memory

Tags: operating-system

I know that Memory tables are used to keep track of main memory and secondary memory. Also OS needs to maintain some sort of information about each processes in order to fetch the contents from secondary memory but I have few questions in regards to the above:

1) Main memory is limited and CPU can directly access only Main Memory and there can be many many number of processes, so how is it possible that each of the processes information is maintained by the CPU in Main memory. (even though only small part of the Process Image of each process is kept in memory but still there can be so many processes)

2) Also Secondary Memory can be in TBs so how are the addresses accessed as it would definitely require more than 32 bits to represent TBs. Eg. Some data of a Process is at location beginning from 900 GB. How will the PCB of that process tell the CPU that it is at location 900 GB, I mean it has to take more than 32 bits to tell that right and assume the system is 32 bit and how will it be different if the system is 64 bit.

3) Also the secondary memory being in TBs, there has to be some way for the CPU to access any part of the Secondary Memory, how is that done?

4) Also is the case possible where there is no information about the process in Main memory. If that is the case then how would the retrieval of the contents of that data would be carried out. This might not be the case but the thing that forces me to think in this perspective is that the Main memory is only so much and there can be lots and lots of processes, hence the question.

I have tried searching a lot on internet but unable to find answers and if I find something I get more confused. Can anyone please clarify these doubts.

Edit: Take any CPU or any OS, I just want a generalized picture. The specifics may be different in different systems but I believe at some level there will be some commonality.

Comment: What CPU and what OS? Do you imagine that every CPU and every operating system ever designed work identically?

Comment: Take any CPU or any OS, I just want a generalized picture. The specifics may be different in different systems but I believe at some level there will be some commonality.

Answer (score 1):

Terabytes? No problem.

You can always construct longer integers out of shorter ones. File systems very often use indices, sizes and counts longer in bits than the size of the pointer in the CPU. That's how you can have and address more storage than the size of the CPU's address space.

And you don't need to load everything from the disk into the RAM, you can load just enough and in small pieces fitting into the address space of the CPU.

File systems let you read data blocks that comprise files and directories one or more at a time and those blocks are typically on the order of kilobytes in size, not megabytes or gigabytes, let alone terabytes.

So, longer indices/sizes/counts + small blocks. That's all you need to access more on-disk data than can be loaded into the RAM.

Comment: But how would the CPU know which part of the secondary memory to get in the Main Memory - true that the PCB of the process will hold that information but if the location of the information needed is say 
900 GB, then will the PCB have longer indices that would point to that location?

Comment: Also is the case possible where there is no information about the process in Main memory. If that is the case then how would the retrieval of the contents of that data would be carried out. This might not be the case but the thing that forces me to think in this perspective is that the Main memory is only so much and there can be lots and lots of processes, hence the question.

Comment: In order to read data from the disk, you first need to write data to the disk. When you write a file to the disk, you get the file ID from the file system. The file system will then will be able to figure out where the file starts on the media, given the file name or ID. Also, when you write the file to the disk, you know how much you write, and at which location within the file the data of interest is. You then use this info to request a block of data from the file at or near this location and the file system does the rest.

Comment: Further, you may write additional "meta" data into the file, describing the file structure (think of the various multimedia files, they do have structure and special control info besides the pixel colors and audio samples; think of HTML/XML as well as another example of structured data). That way even if there's no trace of a process in the RAM, you can find its info in the file by parsing it.

Comment: Ok so just to make sure I have got you right, when you open any file or content, the metadata that the CPU gets by parsing it gets loaded in the Main Memory and I assume this metadata would have PCB and all other structures and hence even if there is no info of the process in Main memory it still can be accessed. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you have previously stored it there, you'll get it back, unless the FS or media is damaged. Come on, you have used files before, haven't you?

Comment: Have used but haven't thought about it or haven't really understood so just trying to understand it as completely as possible. Thanks for your answers.